# Simple primality test

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primality-test

I am an amateur and have been doing some number theory for fun, so I apologize if my post is absolutely trivial:)

I have been playing with primality tests and I thought of the following method:
Pick a number that you want to test for primality, say 13.List all whole number addends of the number as pairs:

1  12

2  11

3  10

4   9

5   8

6   7

If all pairs are relatively prime (no number greater than 1 can be "factored out"), the number is prime.

This is all pretty simple but I wanted to know where is this mentioned in the literature and where one could go from here to improve the algorithm or expand on this simple idea.

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't that get very complicated for the confirming that 100,003 is prime?  For very small primes, that may be a handy observation, but not for testing primes, in general.

Comment: You might as well just test every number from $2$ to $n/2$ to see if it divides $n$.  This takes far too long.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

Comment: You might like to review methods at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test and https://primes.utm.edu/curios/includes/primetest.php

Comment: Congratulations, your method works! However, as has been pointed out in other comments, it is no better than trial division ($\gcd(d,n-d)>1\iff \gcd(d,n)>1\iff d\mid n$ for $1\le d\le \frac n2$)  and therefore is feasible only for smallish $n$

Comment: It's a nice observation, and nicely presented (which is not always the case when amateurs post descriptions of their discoveries). I would heartily encourage you to take a look at Conway and Guy's *Book of Numbers*, to further your fun with number theory.

Comment: You would like the "sieve of Eratosthenes".  I believe he only goes up to $\sqrt n$, as it's all that is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not mentioned in the literature, but you can prove it like this. Suppose that $n$ is your number and that $p$ is a prime dividing $n$. Let $q = n - p$, so that one line of your list will be
$$ p + q = n.$$
As $p$ divides $p$ and $p$ divides $n$, we get that $p$ divides $q$. Thus a nontrivial divisor will lead to at least one line where all terms share a common factor.

More generally, if $a$ is any number that shares a nontrivial factor $p$ with $n$, and $a + b = n$, then $p$ must also divide $b$. From this point of view, to show a number is not prime in this method amounts to finding another number that shares a common factor with $n$. This is very similar to trial division --- just looking at all numbers less than $n$ for a common factor.

However you can give speedups analogous to those for trial division. It's only necessary to list those numbers $a \leq \sqrt{n}$ in your list to look for something with a common factor, for example.